# Record and hear the data from a udp socket

Tags: java, sockets, voip, rtp, javax.sound.sampled

I was developing a softphone with record facility
(I am using **mjsip** library)

1. If it is hearing only using javax.sound.* its works fine
2. If write the incoming data to a file it  also works.

But it I try to do both at same time using two threads the voice is distorted. It is something like **voice becomes faster**

Can anybody help?

```
reciver1=new RtpStreamReceiver(audio_output_stream,socket);
receiver1.start();

File file=new File("sample.raw");
FileOutputStream output_stream=new FileOutputStream(file);
reciver2=new RtpStreamReceiver(output_stream,socket);
receiver2.start();

Both receiver1 ans receiver2 are extending Thread and will do the transfer of stream
```

Comment: What's your code like? Are you buffering the data you're receiving, or just expecting that the previous data has been played already, when receiving new data?

Comment: I am not using any buffering... in the code will work fine with either storing the file, or hearing..... I just wanted to modify it to do both at same time

Comment: Then you'll need to buffer it. Show your code.